# Using Behave I want to run all my feature files but it throws error No steps directory but the same runs through pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

When I use this command to run behave /ios_integration/features I get the ConfigError: no Steps directory

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prv0Q.png]

Comment: What is "this command"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct command would be:

```
behave ios_integration/features
```

(no preceeding slash)

Comment: If I do so, I get the following error.  ```File "ios_integration/features/environment.py", line 4, in <module>
    from features.commonFunctions import commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features.commonFunctions' ```

Comment: Assuming your working directory is `alaya-mobile-automation`, that import in `environment.py` should state `from ios_integration.features.commonFunctions...`